# How to type Big And symbol?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

how to type the symbol in the photo with ieeetrans, basically what it means is
`t1<=t2` and `t1<=t3` ... and `t1<=tn`.

[image]

Comment: loved the drawings hahahah

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is my version, the top one is what I believe to see in the image, the bottom one is what you've described in your question.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\[ \bigwedge\limits_{i=2}^k t_i \leq t_k \]
\[ \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n t_1 \leq t_i \]

\end{document}
```

[image: different versions of and]

Comment: The `\limits` is not necessary. `\bigwedge` is a unary operator and already has `\limits` applied to it as a result.