# How to write constraints above or below logical operators in latex?

Tags: math-operators, logic

I want to write constraints below logical operators like or. How do I do it. There is a question already on AND [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64989/how-to-type-big-and-symbol), how do I do it for OR operator/ other operators like implication etc?

Comment: Use `\overset` and `\underset`, as described here: [Typeset an = with an ! above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6195/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For or, the command would be `\bigvee` although `\bigwedge` and `\bigvee` are symbols which are intended to be used as operators on some set or range of values, e.g.,

```
 \[
   \bigwedge_{i=1}^{10} F_{i}
 \]
```

to indicate that you're essentially calculating

> *F*₁ ∧ *F*₂ ∧ ⋯ ∧ *F*₁₀

I'm not sure that makes sense for ⇒ which is likely why no such operator is predefined. If you perhaps mean that you want to put some text above or below ⇒ you can load `amsmath` and use the command `\overset`, `\underset` or `\overunderset`, e.g.,

```
\[
   A \overset{*}{\Rightarrow} B
\]
```

to set ⇒ with a * above it. You would do something similar if you wanted to put symbols above or below `\wedge`, `\vee`, etc.